# Unity 3D collision without physics

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game I have 2 objects. I want them to be able to collide and not go through each other. Currently Collision is working, but when one object pushes the other, he other starts floating away. I don't want that. How can I get collisions(not going through each other) without the physics(floating away, pushing, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

The component that makes the gameobject react to external forces applied on it is the Rigidbody

-You can configure constraints on your rigidbody so the passive physics (forces coming outside the object, like gravity and collisions) won't work in the axis you block. Only active forces will (like AddForce() method)
[Ridigbody Component in Editor with all constraints enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCKqi.png)

-In static objects (like walls, a tree) you can remove the rigidbody components. It will enhance performance too. Only use rigidbody in dynamic objects like characters, vehicles, balls, bullets

-Between A and B object, at least one of them must have rigidbody, or the collision detection won't be possible (in the object which contains the method OnCollisionEnter (or Stay)

But be careful. Without the rigidbody, you won't be able to use the AddForce() method to move object. If you use simply the Translate method on the Transform, the collision detection will become a such unaccurate

Comment: Currently the issue is solved by using CharacterController instead of rigidbody.